# What does $\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}[i, i+2]$ mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I think I get it but I wanted to be sure before attempting the question:

**Question**

Describe the following set, and prove your answers correct. (Here brackets
denote intervals on $\mathbb{R}$.)

$\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}[i, i+2]$

Does it mean: {$0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...,\infty$} $\cup$ {$2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,...,\infty$}?

If so, what is the difference between:

$\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}[i, i+2]$ and $\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}(i, i+2)$

Comment: It means $[0,2] \cup [1,3] \cdots$. Therefore, the number $0.5$ is in the set.

Comment: $[i,i+2]=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid i\leq x\leq i+2\right\}$. These are simply intervals.

Comment: To address your confusion, for some countable collection of sets $\{S_i\}_{i=0}^{\infty}$we define  

$$\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} S_i$$

so that 

$$\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} S_i = \{x \ | \exists i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \ \text{such that}\ x \in S_i\} $$

In this context (well, in almost all contexts), $\infty$ is not referring to a number! If you have the symbol $\infty$ as an actual 'thing' inside a set, you're probably doing something wrong (unless you're talking about the extended reals)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a simpler description of the following set: $\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}[i, i+2]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275785/find-a-simpler-description-of-the-following-set-bigcup-i-0-inftyi-i2)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No, the duplicate is the other question. He actually says so at the beginning of it.

Answer (score 2):

In the usual notation, for intervals in the real line $\mathbb{R}$, $[a,b]$ means the **closed** interval from $a$ to $b$. On the other hand, the notation $(a,b)$ means **open** interval.

In your question, following this notation, you are dealing with an infinite union of closed intervals. In particular,
$$[0,2]\cup[1,3]\cup[2,4]\cup\dots\cup[k,k+2]\cup\dots$$

Comment: So would the answer be $[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,..., /infty]$?

Comment: Well, like I said in the answer, the result is $[0,2]\cup[1,3]\cup[2,4]\cup\dots\cup[k,k+2]\cup\dots$ which can be written as $[0,\infty)$. You may want to have a look at the definition an usage of the union operation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)

Answer (score 0):

$\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty [i,i+2]$ means the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\exists i\in\mathbb{Z^+\cup\{0\}}\ \text{such that}\ x\in[i,i+2]\}$. And $\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty (i,i+2)$ means the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\exists i\in\mathbb{Z^+}\cup\{0\}\ \text{such that}\ x\in(i,i+2)\}$. The most obvious difference is that $0$ is a member of the former set while it is not a member of the latter.