# Find a simpler description of the following set: $\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}[i, i+2]$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I asked a similar question last night asking for an explanation of the statement, however I was unable to find how to prove such a statement, so I have a proof, however I think it is wrong, so I'm just asking for it to be checked and if it is, for it to be corrected, thanks!

**Question**

Describe the following set, and prove your answer correct. (Here brackets
denote intervals on $\mathbb{R}$.)

$\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}[i, i+2]$

**Working**

$[i,i+2]=${$x\in\mathbb{R}|i\leq x\leq i+2$}

Thus, with the union we have {$x\in\mathbb{R}|i\leq x\leq i+2$}$=[0, \infty)$

Now, note that $\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}[i, i+2]=[0, 2]\cup [1, 3]\cup [2,4]\cup...\cup[k, k+2]\cup...$ for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$

Consider $x \notin [0, \infty)$ then $|x|>[0, \infty)$, so $\exists$ some $i\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $i<|x|$. Thus, $x\notin (0, \infty]$

$\therefore x$ is not the union

Thus, we have shown the union of $[i, i+2]$ is on the interval $[0, \infty)$ so;

$\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}[i, i+2]=[0, \infty)$

Comment: Your question title does not contain any statement.

Comment: I'd prove this in 2 parts, first prove that ⋃∞i=0[i,i+2] is a sub set of [0,∞) then prove that [0,∞) is a subset of ⋃∞i=0[i,i+2].    to do so, prove every element x in the first set is also in the second. do this for each then they must be equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have all the right ideas here. Your notation is somewhat confusing in some spots, and you perhaps mention more than is necessary. Here is a short summary:

Suppose $x\ge 0$. Then for some $i\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}$, we have $x\in [i,i+2]$, so $x\in\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty[i,i+2]$. Suppose $x<0$. Then for all $i\ge 0$, we have $x<i$, so $x\not\in[i,i+2]$, and thus $x\not\in\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty[i,i+2]$. Thus, we have shown $$\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty[i,i+2]=[0,\infty).$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: You have $ \lfloor x \rfloor \le x \le \lfloor x \rfloor + 1 < \lfloor x \rfloor  + 2$